# How do i define a custom file path in c?

Tags: c, windows, path

I'm trying to make it so a file name which is created using character arrays and `strcat` is created in a folder which is also created using character arrays and `strcat`. However, when I try to define the file path in the `fopen()` function, it refuses to compile.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

char spaceadder (char array[100]) {
  int i, count = -1;
  for(i = 0; array[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    count++;
  }
  array[count + 1] = ' ';
  array[count + 2] = '\0';

  return array;
}

int main(void) {
  char make[50], model[50], reg[100], folderName[100], fileName[100];
  FILE *fp;

  printf("Reg: ");
  scanf("%s", reg);
  printf("Enter the Make and Model of the Vehicle: ");
  scanf("%s %s", make, model);

  strcpy(folderName, make);
  spaceadder(folderName);
  strcat(folderName, model);
  spaceadder(folderName);
  strcat(folderName, reg);

  mkdir(folderName, 0777);

  strcpy(fileName, "AD ");
  strcat(fileName, reg);

  fp = fopen(folderName\\fileName, "w");
  fclose(fp);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can use `snprintf` to format a string with the wanted path. No need for your `spaceadder` function or the `strcpy`/`strcat` calls either.

Comment: I do apologise, do you have an example of that using the existing code? I'm just having trouble wrapping my head around the snprintf() function

Comment: You use any of the formatted output family of functions the same way. Do you know how to use printf? You know how to use snprintf.

Comment: For example `snprintf(folderName, sizeof folderName, "%s %s %s", make. model, reg)`